# sqlite3 how to select the value of a column that matches another column name

Tags: sqlite

If you just create a blank file "touch foo.db" then run this script (test.sql) as "sqlite3 foo.db < test.sql" (half this code is just for formatting the output):

```
.timer off
.headers off
.mode column
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test;
CREATE TABLE Test ("Name" TEXT, "Value" INT);
INSERT INTO Test (Name, Value) VALUES ("A", 1);
INSERT INTO Test (Name, Value) VALUES ("B", 2);
INSERT INTO Test (Name, Value) VALUES ("Value", 3);
SELECT "Query 1 - EVERYTHING" FROM Test WHERE rowid = 1;
SELECT "=====" FROM Test WHERE rowid = 1;
SELECT * FROM Test;
SELECT "Query 2 - EQUALS" FROM Test WHERE rowid = 1;
SELECT "=====" FROM Test WHERE rowid = 1;
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Name = "Value";
SELECT "Query 3 - LIKE" FROM Test WHERE rowid = 1;
SELECT "=====" FROM Test WHERE rowid = 1;
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Name LIKE "Value%";
SELECT "Query 4 - Recursive" FROM Test WHERE rowid = 1;
SELECT "=====" FROM Test WHERE rowid = 1;
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE Value = 3);
```

Gives the following results:

```
Query 1 - EVERYTHING  
=====     
A           1         
B           2         
Value       3         
Query 2 - EQUALS  
=====     
Query 3 - LIKE  
=====     
Value       3         
Query 4 - Recursive  
=====     
Value       3
```

This seems to indicate sqlite is changing the value of "Value" upon insert since the LIKE and recursion work. Is this a bug in sqlite or is there's something I can do to make the = work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SQLite Keywords doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

> 'keyword'      A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
>
> "keyword"     A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.

Try this `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Name = 'Value';` instead because `Value` is an identifier, ie column name.

Comment: Oh thank you, I apparently lack the reputation to upvote :( but that was it.

Comment: AFAIK you can [accept the anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not change the values of the columns.

The problem is the use of `"Value"` in your queries.

From [SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

> If a keyword in double quotes (ex: "key" or "glob") is used in a
> context where it **cannot** be resolved to an identifier but where a
> string literal is allowed, then the token is understood to be a string
> literal instead of an identifier.

In this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Name = "Value";
```

`"Value"` **can** be resolved to an identifier (the column `"Value"` of the table) and so it is resolved to that identifier and the query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Name = Value;
```

which does not return any rows.

This is why you should always use single quotes for string literals:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Name = 'Value';
```